# Alternatives to Cognito in AWS GovCloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

My team has built a Serverless Web Application in AWS using Cognito User Pools for allowing users to register on the site and authenticate to it. We are now needing to move this application into a GovCloud (US) region, which does not support the Cognito Service.

1) Is it possible to host Cognito in another region and still use it to authenticate access to the API gateway inside a GovCloud region?

2) If no on #1, what is a good alternative that IS available in GovCloud regions for user sign-up and auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just yesterday, May 13 2020 Amazon announced Cognito availability in GovCloud

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/05/amazon-cognito-is-now-available-in-the-aws-govcloud-us-west-region/

[Not all the features of Cognito are available](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/govcloud-us/latest/UserGuide/govcloud-cog.html), like for example Authorizers for API Gateway, so YMMV.

Comment: Awesome news. It's about time!